# SQL Query : How to Get Last Month Closing Balance, Current Month Current Balance and Current Month ending Balance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a View which returns data from joining multiple tables with the fields:

```
TransactionID
FiscalMonthID
CurrencyID
AccountID
TransactionDate
TransactionNo
TransactionDetails
AccountCode
AccountName
CurrencyName
AmountDebit
AmountCredit
```

Now based on the above fields i want to create a Crystal Report which returns a Periodic Trial Balance like this:

**Statement from Date to Date (i.e. 1/01/2012 - 29/02/2012)**

```
[AccountCode] - [AccountName] - [OpeningBalance] - [Current Balance (Dr./Cr.)] - [Closing Balance(Dr./Cr.)]
```

Note: Opening balance must be the closing balance of previous month that will carry forward to next month and will become opening balance.

Comment: Just using this logic will create an incorrect balance statement at the start of a year. P&L of last year should not roll over to the current year. Balance sheet accounts should.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if you perform a cumulative total (year to date) grouped per month, you will get what you are looking for, not calculating individual months at a time.